# Age Validation Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

Have this so far but wont work?

```
//if no age was entered it will allow
var age=document.getElementById('age1').value;
if(age == "")     
    return true;

//check if age is a number or less than or greater than 100
if (isNaN(age)||age<1||age>100)
{ 
    alert("The age must be a number between 1 and 100");
    return false;
}
```

I just need to validate!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the regular expression to validate this. Use below regular expression for this:

```
/^[1-9]?[0-9]{1}$|^100$/
```

This regex which matches a number of 1 or 2 digits, or 100:

Comment: Good suggestion but you would want to give a more concrete regular expression pattern. Try your regex against `donotmatch100`, `donotmatch10or0` and `donotmatch10or0orme`.

Answer (score 1):

try shortcut `+` to convert into `Number`, or use `parseInt(value, 10)`

```
var age = +document.getElementById('age1').value;

if ( !( age > 1 && age<100 ) ){

        alert("The age must be a number between 1 and 100");
        return false;
}

return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to parseInt() the value you get back into age, since it comes in as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your string to a number using `parseInt(value, radix)`. It's a good practice to provide the `radix` when using this method. In your case it is a decimal so the `radix` is `10`.

Try this:

```
//if no age was entered it will allow
var age=document.getElementById('age1').value;
if(age === "") {
  return true;
}

// convert age to a number
age = parseInt(age, 10);

//check if age is a number or less than or greater than 100
if (isNaN(age) || age < 1 || age > 100)
{ 
  alert("The age must be a number between 1 and 100");
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type='text' name='dob' onblur="Age_validator(this.value)" style='width:108px;' />
<div><span id="dob1"></span></div>
function Age_validator(str){
    // which user inputs
    str = str.split("-");
    var dd = str[0];
    var mm = str[1];
    var yy = str[2];
    // Current date calculation
    var d = new Date();
    var ds = d.getDate();
    var ms = d.getMonth();
    var ys = d.getFullYear();
    // convert 18years as days from current date
    var days = ((18 * 12) * 30) + (ms * 30) + ds;
    // convert days from input value
    var age = (((ys - yy) * 12) * 30) + ((12 - mm) * 30) + parseInt(30 - dd);

    if((days - age) <= '0'){
        console.log((days - age));
        document.getElementById('dob1').innerHTML = 'Valid';
        // or return your own script
    }else{
        console.log((days - age));
        document.getElementById('dob1').innerHTML = 'Invalid';
        // or return your own script
    }
}
```

**Please +1 if it useful**

Answer (score 0):

Try this works form me :)

```
var dateString = document.getElementById("age1").value;
if(dateString !=""){
  var today = new Date();
  var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
  var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  var da = today.getDate() - birthDate.getDate();
  if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
  }
  if(m<0){
    m +=12;
  }
  if(da<0){
    da +=30;
  }
  if (age >= 1 && age <= 99) {
    return true;
  }else {
    return false;
  }

}else {
  return false;
}
```

Also you can use other libraries to calculate time like moment https://momentjs.com/ that can make easier time calculations (seconds, minutes, hours, days, years, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, minimum age of 18 and a maximum of 70

```
validateAge(year,month,day) {

    const max_year = new Date().getFullYear() - 70 ;
    const min_year = new Date().getFullYear() - 18 ;
    const _month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    const _day = new Date().getDay();

    const dateofbirthDate = new Date(year + "-"+month+"-"+day);
    const mindate = new Date( min_year+ '-'+_month+'-'+_day);
    const maxdate = new Date(max_year+ '-'+_month+'-'+_day);


    if(dateofbirthDate <= mindate && dateofbirthDate >= maxdate){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false; 
}
```